# GDB doesn't show source code when using list command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debugging, gdb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to debug a segfault, but it seems that some common `gdb` commands aren't working as expected. If I do the following:

```
gdb ./executable_name
break main
run
list
```

I get the following error:

```
(gdb) list
1   <built-in>: No such file or directory.
```

Similarly, if I let the program run until it segfaults, and then try and inspect a particular frame in the stack using

```
bt
up
list
```

I get a similar but shorter error:

```
(gdb) list
1   in <built-in>
```

I've used GDB on other Ubuntu-based systems before and haven't had a problem like this, so I'm assuming I still need to set GDB up correctly on my system so that it knows where to look for an executable's corresponding source code. Would anyone know how I could get GDB to display source code whilst using the `list` command when debugging?

Comment: How is the executable built?

Comment: Apologies, I should have looked more before asking this. This executable was not build in debug mode. I'm using `ROS` and `catkin`, so using `catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` solved the problem. Could this question be closed?

Comment: @indigoblue You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked more before asking the above question. The above executable was not built in debug mode. I'm using `ROS` and `catkin`, so using `catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` in the package directory solved the problem.